# How to run the same regression with different y

Tags: r

Noob coder here, so I would appreciate your help:)

Im trying to run the same regression with different y variables. Basically I need to run a results = lm(stock ~ beta, data=d) regression, but I have 103 different stocks to run the same regression with monthly data (103 stocks, 100 months per stock)

I need to regress the excess returns of 103 different stocks on the same beta (my X variable) for every regression. At the moment I am just changing the stock manually, but this is extremely time consuming and annoying.

Comment: @divibisan `x~beta` is of class formula thus cannot directly be manipulated with `lapply`. Your approache is incorrect`.

Comment: @onyambu Good catch. I suppose you could stick in `as.formula` to make it work, but your approach is much more elegant

Comment: @divibisan you could loop by using names and `sprintf` ie `lapply(names(mtcars[-1]), function(x) lm(paste0(x, ' ~ mpg'), mtcars))` `lm` takes a character string that looks like a formula and transforms it into a formula. Note that the solution I provided uses partial regression\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lm` allows for multiple regressions all at once.

use

```
 lm(as.matrix(stocks)~d$beta)
```

A quick example is to use the `mtcars` dataset

```
lm(as.matrix(mtcars[-1])~mpg, mtcars)


Call:
lm(formula = as.matrix(mtcars[-1]) ~ mpg, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
             cyl        disp       hp         drat       wt         qsec       vs         am         gear       carb     
(Intercept)   11.26068  580.88382  324.08231    2.38249    6.04726   15.35477   -0.67817   -0.59149    2.50627    5.77880
mpg           -0.25251  -17.42912   -8.82973    0.06043   -0.14086    0.12414    0.05553    0.04966    0.05880   -0.14765
```